# PHPStorm - Como criar um arquivo Patch ignorando espaços em branco

Tags: git, phpstorm

Consigo gerar um arquivo Patch com as mudanças para ser comitado no git.

Como eu posso gerar esse arquivo Patch, ignorando os espaços em brancos assim como eu faço na tela View Changes?

Alguns arquivos antigos tem tabs ao invés de 4 espaços e alguns espaços em branco sobrando no final, na diff view eu consigo ignora-los, mas como fazer isso no Patch para não virar uma bagunça?

Comment: Este artigo deve te ajudar: [git patch does not apply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770177/git-patch-does-not-apply).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usuário @jbaptperez em um comentário, recomendou um link para leitura que resolveu meu problema:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770177/git-patch-does-not-apply

A resposta foi:

```
git apply --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace mychanges.patch
```

Obrigado.